# How to get the SQL duplicate with different details in single line.?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, duplicates

I want

1) Gmail type of Email Prefred + OTHER EMAIL Prefered. 
*(if there are no other Email type then NULL in EMAIL2, TYPE2, PREFERED_IND2)*

2) Gmail type of Email not prefred but OTHER EMAIL is Prefred. 
*(if there are no other Email type then NULL in EMAIL2, TYPE2, PREFERED_IND2)*

Table:

```
ID | NAME | EMAIL           | TYPE    | PREFERED_IND
1  | XYZ  | xyz@gmail.com   | gmail   | Y
1  | XYZ  | xyz@yahoo.com   | yahoo   | Y
2  | ABC  | abc@gmail.com   | gmail   | N
2  | ABC  | abc@hotmail.com | hotmail | Y
```

Query response 1

```
ID | NAME | EMAIL         | TYPE  | PREFERED_IND | EMAIL2        | TYPE2 | PREFERED_IND2
1  | XYZ  | xyz@gmail.com | gmail | Y            | xyz@yahoo.com | yahoo | Y
```

Query response 2

```
ID | NAME | EMAIL         | TYPE  | PREFERED_IND | EMAIL2          | TYPE2   | PREFERED_IND2
 2 | ABC  | abc@gmail.com | gmail | N            | abc@hotmail.com | hotmail | Y
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT ID, Full_Name, TYPE, EMAIL_ADDRESS, PREFERRED_IND 
FROM A 
JOIN A y ON (y.ID = ID) 
WHERE (TYPE != 'GMAIL' AND ( ID IN (SELECT x.ID 
           FROM A x WHERE x.TYPE = 'GMAIL' AND x.PREFERRED_IND = 'Y') ) )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT 
    ID, 
    Full_Name, 
    TYPE,
    EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
 PREFERRED_IND
FROM A
    JOIN A y ON (y.ID = ID)
WHERE (TYPE != 'GMAIL' AND 
    (
        ID IN (SELECT x.ID FROM A x 
                        WHERE x.TYPE = 'GMAIL' 
                        AND x.PREFERRED_IND = 'Y')
    )
)

Comment: I actually removed the gmail ones and only get the one which are preferred. but i want to have both in single line.I was a bit off tracked.

Comment: FYI never put code in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: Ok will update it. thanks

Comment: How do you decide which is email 1 and which is email 2 - is it just that type gmail is always first (so preference flag isn't relevant - and is it right that more than one is preferred)? What is they don't have a gmail account at all but only an 'other' - would that still be email 2 and email 1 would be null? What if they have more than two email addresses int he original table?

Comment: where does that full _name column come from?

Comment: I got it. Please check what i was expecting to be solved. I was trying to join columns of same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    orignal.ID, 
    orignal.Full_Name, 
    orignal.TYPE, 
    orignal.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
    orignal.PREFERRED_IND,
    joined.TYPE,
    joined.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    joined.PREFERED_IND
FROM A orignal
    JOIN A joined ON    (
                            joined.ID = orignal.ID
                            AND joined.TYPE = 'GMAIL'
                        ) 
WHERE  orignal.TYPE != 'GMAIL'
AND orignal.PREFERRED_IND = 'Y'
AND orignal.ID IN   (
                        SELECT
                            temp.ID
                        FROM A temp
                        WHERE temp.TYPE = 'GMAIL'
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to pivot, though it's unclear quite how you want the data to be displayed if it doesn't match your sample (more email addresses for a single user, no GMail address at all, etc.). A manual pivot would be something like:

```
select id, name,
  max(case when type = 'gmail' then email_address end) as email1,
  max(case when type = 'gmail' then type end) as type1,
  max(case when type = 'gmail' then preferred_ind end) as preferred_ind1,
  max(case when type != 'gmail' then email_address end) as email2,
  max(case when type != 'gmail' then type end) as type2,
  max(case when type != 'gmail' then preferred_ind end) as preferred_ind2
from a
group by id, name;
```

With your data as a CTE (picking consistent names, which might not match your actual table, again that is unclear) and including a couple of other scenarios:

```
with a (ID, NAME, EMAIL_address, TYPE, PREFERrED_IND) as (
            select 1, 'XYZ', 'xyz@gmail.com', 'gmail', 'Y' from dual
  union all select 1, 'XYZ', 'xyz@yahoo.com', 'yahoo', 'Y' from dual
  union all select 2, 'ABC', 'abc@gmail.com', 'gmail', 'N' from dual
  union all select 2, 'ABC', 'abc@hotmail.com', 'hotmail', 'Y' from dual
  union all select 3, 'DEF', 'def@gmail.com', 'gmail', 'Y' from dual
  union all select 4, 'GHI', 'ghi@hotmail.com', 'hotmail', 'Y' from dual
)
select id, name,
  max(case when type = 'gmail' then email_address end) as email1,
  max(case when type = 'gmail' then type end) as type1,
  max(case when type = 'gmail' then preferred_ind end) as preferred_ind1,
  max(case when type != 'gmail' then email_address end) as email2,
  max(case when type != 'gmail' then type end) as type2,
  max(case when type != 'gmail' then preferred_ind end) as preferred_ind2
from a
group by id, name
order by id;

        ID NAME EMAIL1          TYPE1   PREFERRED_IND1 EMAIL2          TYPE2   PREFERRED_IND2
---------- ---- --------------- ------- -------------- --------------- ------- --------------
         1 XYZ  xyz@gmail.com   gmail   Y              xyz@yahoo.com   yahoo   Y             
         2 ABC  abc@gmail.com   gmail   N              abc@hotmail.com hotmail Y             
         3 DEF  def@gmail.com   gmail   Y                                                    
         4 GHI                                         ghi@hotmail.com hotmail Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are always two rows for each ID and that only one of them is Gmail, you can do a simple join:

> ```
> select a1.*, a2.email email2, a2.type type2, a2.preferred_ind preferred_ind2
> from a a1 join a a2 on a2.id = a1.id and a1.type = 'gmail' and a2.type <> 'gmail'
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | NAME | EMAIL         | TYPE  | PREFERRED_IND | EMAIL2          | TYPE2   | PREFERRED_IND2
> -: | :--- | :------------ | :---- | :------------ | :-------------- | :------ | :-------------
>  1 | XYZ  | xyz@gmail.com | gmail | Y             | xyz@yahoo.com   | yahoo   | Y             
>  2 | ABC  | abc@gmail.com | gmail | N             | abc@hotmail.com | hotmail | Y
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=96928f73fe1d3eb4cad9859495781d29)*